# Windows 10 - Reboot via RDP (without using the keyboard)

Tags: windows-10, reboot

I'm looking for a way to restart a Window 10 PC, while being logged into it via RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) **without using the keyboard**. In Windows 7, this could be done [easily](https://youtu.be/26-3zguFgL4) (4 clicks - no keyboard).

I'm already aware of these methods in Windows 10:

1. ALT-F4 (no good - requires keyboard).
2. command: shutdown -r (no good - requires keyboard).

So, does anyone know of a method of restarting (via RDP) that does not require even one keystroke on the keyboard?

Comment: Start button (left bottom of screen) - restart?

Comment: Normally that would work, but when you're logged into Windows 10 via RDP, that option is not available (only "Disconnect" is available in the menu you're indicating).

Comment: save a text file containing `shutdown -r` string, double-click, copy-paste to cmd ;)

Comment: use PSExec to connect to the system from a computer that has a keyboard, and issue the shutdown command that way.

Comment: I can't test it at the moment, but before Windows 10, you could run Task Manager and select Restart or Shutdown from menu. Googling shows that this option could have disappeared in the meantime and definitely it's not there when running on console.

Comment: I use 2 bat files, saved on the desktop, one with `shutdown.exe /p /f` to shutdown & the other with `shutdown.exe /r /f /t 00 ` to reboot. Double-click to action, no keyboard required.

Comment: I thought RDP with user that's admin on machine will allow you to shutdown/restart.

Comment: @Terry - the admin can shutdown, but not from the start menu where the shutdown is when you are local. I assume that's to minimize accidentally shutting down a remote system.

Comment: @LonnieBest - is there some specific situation where this is coming up for you? Is there an underlying problem that forces you to not use the keyboard?

Comment: @MichaelKohne - No, it is my preference to use the mouse exclusively for rebooting like I did via RDP in Windows 7, as shown here (4 clicks): https://youtu.be/26-3zguFgL4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested, a batch file somewhere with the command `shutdown /r /t 0` would give you something to double click to reboot. But, thinking outside the box, you could also:

1. Navigate to `Start` -> `All Apps` -> `Windows Ease of Access` -> `On-Screen Keyboard`

[image]

2. Click the desktop, click `Alt`, `Fn`, `F4`. You will get a dialog box with a restart option.

[image]

Alternatively, you could Right Click the taskbar and enable the `Touch Keyboard` button, and type out a shutdown command from here. Really though, making a batch file would be a much easier way. All other power options have been replaced with `Disconnect` by design, and I suspect the `Alt` + `F4` trick is an oversight.

Comment: Is there anything similar to the method in Windows 7 (4 clicks): https://youtu.be/26-3zguFgL4   ? I'm not interested in using virtual keyboards either to achieve this task.